# Word count graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings, ascii-art, data-visualization

I created a program in python that reads a file and outputs a frequency graph of the words it contains. Any feedback or tips would be appreciated.

```
from re import split
from collections import Counter

size = int(input("Output window size(in chars): "))
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
  words = [w for w in split(r"[\W_\d]+", f.read().strip()) if w]
if not words:
  print("Put some text in `text.txt`!")
  quit()
word_count = Counter(words)
top_words = sorted(word_count.keys(), key = lambda w : word_count[w], reverse = True)
scale = (size - len(max(top_words, key = len))) / word_count[top_words[0]]
for word in top_words[:10]:
  print("-" * (int(word_count[word] * scale) - 2) + "| " + word)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Review

- The Python style guide [[PEP8]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) advises to use 4 space indentation
- You don't have to sort the words

  `Counter` has some features that allow you to get the most common occurrences, aptly named [most_common()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)
- String formatting is cleaner vs manual string appending

  Instead of manually concatenating use `str.format()` or even `f"{string}"` with Python3.6+

### Code

Using these additions we can rewrite your last code block into:

```
word_count = Counter(words)
scale = (size - max(map(len, word_count))) / word_count.most_common(1)[0][1]
for word, occurence in word_count.most_common(10):
    print("{}| {}".format("-" * int(occurence * scale - 2), word))
```

Comment: Wouldn't `max(len(word) for word in word_count)` or `max(map(len, word_count))` be a lot easier than calling `max` with `len` as the key and then calling `len` on it again?

Comment: Ohh I like `max(map(len, word_count))` didn't cross my mind to write it this way!

Comment: You want to scale to the longest word in top ten, not the longest word in the whole corpus.   Also `.most_common` is presumably \$O(n)\$ in the number of unique words; it would be better to retrieve the top ten once and take the top one from there.

Comment: @OhMyGoodness "You want to scale to the longest word in top ten, not the longest word in the whole corpus" **I agree**, but this is not done by OP. It leaves me guessing at their intentions, and I didn't want to deviate from OP's code behavior.

Comment: @Ludisposed OP's code is `len(max(top_words, key = len)))` and it selects longest length from within `top_words`.

Comment: @OhMyGoodness `top_words` is all the words. Don't get me wrong I agree it is probably what OP intended but not wrote